# cannot link postgresdb with django because of UTC

Tags: python, django, postgresql

When i try to connect postgresql, python  terminal returns "database connection isn't set to UTC". How can i solve it? Former answers on this site does not  work.

Comment: Just guessing: set the `timezone` parameter in `postgresql.conf` to `UTC` and reload.

Comment: to complete @LaurenzAlbe comment: if you need more information about pgql time zone SET params check [this link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html)